# Determine number of days (not including weekend) based on hours given

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-arithmetic

I have two important details that are inputted into an excel table, Job_Start_Date and Job_Hours (meaning the hours required to complete the job). Given certain working hours (eg 7:00am-3:30pm) I need to calculate what day and what time they will finish. I already have that basic bit working, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to skip weekends in that calculation (Note that there is a boolean for Sat/Sun that defines whether that day should be skipped).

Here is an example of the data
[image] and an example of the data visualization:    (The DIV errors are because employee count equals 0, pay this no mind.)
[image].

This is the formula used in the visualizer (a massive index match)

```
=IFNA(INDEX(INDIRECT(Allocation!$A$1), MATCH(1,($A3 = INDIRECT(Allocation!$K$1)) 
  * (C$1 >= INDIRECT(Allocation!$C$1)) * (C$1 <= INDIRECT(Allocation!$D$1)) 
  * IF(C$1 = INDIRECT(Allocation!$C$1), ($B3 >= INDIRECT(Allocation!$E$1)), 
  ($B3 >= INDIRECT(Allocation!$I$1))) * IF(C$1 = INDIRECT(Allocation!$D$1), 
  ($B3 < INDIRECT(Allocation!$F$1)), ($B3 < INDIRECT(Allocation!$J$1))), 0)),"")
```

As you can see in the image, Saturdays need to be skipped (being `FALSE`), but it is still shown on the visualizer. However, if I include a statement that matches the Saturday condition (so it only shows up on a Saturday if `TRUE`), it will not alter the end date and thus will not push the final day to Monday.

Essentially the question is: How can I skip days but preserve the 'working hours'. This must be done in excel formulas in the same Job table (first image).

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably looking to incorporate networkdays.intl into that rat's nest of indirects.

Comment: Yeah, the list of indirects isn't great, but unfortunately that was the only way I could get the match working (sadly couldn't get table headers working with it :( )

Judging by the networkdays.intl, it's what I would want, but backwards. I need it to tell me the end date based of the start date and number of days

Comment: Perhaps workday.intl would be a more appropriate function.

Comment: There are workday-related functions you could use.  See [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Formulas-and-functions-294d9486-b332-48ed-b489-abe7d0f9eda9#ID0EAABAAA=More_functions).

Comment: I'm looking at the workday.intl and it's exactly what I will need, but now I am struggling to figure out how to get the correct [workday] value into the function based on which weekends to skip. Any ideas for the sheet functions I could use?

Comment: My best advice would be to [edit] your question to include your best effort at incorporating workday.intl into your problem and describe what it is not going toward your expectations.

Comment: Well I've got it working now, the function was exactly what I wanted, the only thing I dislike with excel is that you can't really do ELSE IF statements without nesting them all. Don't know how to mark the question as answered now either

Comment: Had to do +1 for rat’s nest ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it working using `WORKDAY.INTL`.

First is a nested `IF` to determine which weekend type to use for the workday.intl function

```
Weekend=IF(OR([@[JOB SATURDAY]], [@[JOB SUNDAY]]), IF(AND([@[JOB SATURDAY]], [@[JOB SUNDAY]]), -1, IF([@[JOB SATURDAY]], 11, 17)), 1)
```

Then a second if statement that references that value and then spits out the correct date

```
=IF([@[Weekend]] = -1, [@[JOB START DATE]]+[@[Working Days]], WORKDAY.INTL([@[JOB START DATE]], [@[Working Days]], [@[Weekend]]))
```